# Spring data mongodb and kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-data, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I am running into a problem when using spring data mongodb togheter with kotlin. When i try to read objects from mongodb, i get an error complaining that my data classes don't have a default no-args constructor. I can solve this by giving every field a value in my data class, so the compiler will generate a default no-args constructor. Off course i don't really want to do this.

I know there is a jackson kotlin module and it is included in my maven file. It works for deserializing objects that i get over http, so i know that spring picks it up. It seems however that spring data mongodb doesn't use the jackson objectmapper?

Is there a way i can use the jackson objectmapper in spring data mongodb or fix the problem of not having a non args constructor?

Comment: That's usually a jackson related issue. Jackson, Hibernate and other tools that create objects for you need the object to declare a no-arg constructor. Actually it makes sense, since the framework don't know anything about the values you want to assign in case of arg-constructors. Your question would be better explained with some sample code, by the way.

Comment: A bit late, but show me your data class please. I think you are using default values, aren't you?

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [No-Arg Plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin).
You can add this plugin in you Gradle or Maven Build Script and run your Code without Boilerplate or "Default" Values for your vars.

Very simple example with Gradle:

add Plugin to build.grade

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.1.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}
apply plugin: "kotlin-noarg" // apply "kotlin-jpa" for JPA related annotation
noArg {
    // define annotation, where you need an empty custructor
    annotation("org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document") 
}
```

Create your Document

```
@Document(collection = "simpleDoc")
class SimpleDocument(@Id val id: String, @Field val name: String)
```

Use Spring-Data-REST to create an insert

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/hal+json' -d '{"name":"awesome"}' 'http://localhost:8080/docs'
```

Read your doc

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/hal+json' 'http://localhost:8080/docs/59284d508bc7ee0b4c8fe293'
```